# why the proc sort is way quicker than an insert select

Tags: sql, sas

I have a table with many duplicate lines.

Let's say I have table A with 10 millions lines and a single column without index or primary key.

I did this, first. I created another table , B, and do this

```
INSERT INTO B (col1) SELECT DISTINCT (col1) FROM A;
```

Issue is the performance is slow. Then I found this command

```
proc sort data=A out=B noduprecs; 
by col1;
run;
```

It took only 2 seconds.

Why is it faster therefore better to use a `proc sort`then an `insert select`?

How the proc sort is working and ultimately , be able to deal with so many lines without any indexes?

I could not find anything on the net for the explanations.

TIA

Comment: DISTINCT slows it down.

Comment: Thanks @Jardh. Let's say I'm more looking for an answer on the SAS side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be even faster with

```
proc sort data=A(keep=col1) out=B nodupkey; 
by col1;
run;
```

Try to compare INSERT and SORT with:

```
proc sql;
create table B as select distinct col1 from A;
quit;
```

The experience simply teaches us that PROC SORT is faster than sorting/distinct in PROC SQL implementation. It's just not an official statement, for all situations and not always by such degree.

Is A and B table a SAS BASE libname?

The problem of INSERT version could also be that since the target is predefined, there's surely some checking of value being inserted to fit into target fields, which is maybe less expensive when creating new table.

Comment: Hi @vasja, yes both `A` and `B` are libname based.

Comment: What the `data=A(keep=col1)` is supposed to do?

Comment: It actually reads only field col1 from the source table, as it no other fields existed.

Comment: I downvoted this as I don't believe it answers the question at all.  Additionally, I pretty certain that `PROC SORT` is about the same speed as sorting distinct in `PROC SQL`.  I'll post my own answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

I think we need to know a litle more about your SAS configuration, as I'm definitely not seeing the same results as you.  This is the code I used to test:

**Test code**

Create some test data, 10M rows, with a random integer between 0 and 1000:

```
data x;
  do cnt=1 to 10000000;
    x = floor(rand("Uniform") * 1000);
    output;
  end;
  drop cnt;
run;
```

Try sorting it and keeping distinct values using proc sort.  Run this multiple times to get an average time:

```
proc sort data=x out=test1 nodupkey;
  by x;
run;
```

Try using the proc sql method.  Again, run it multiple times to get an average time:

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table test2 as
  select distinct x
  from x
  order by 1
  ;
quit;
```

Try using the 'insert into' method.  Run multiple times:

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table b like x;
  insert into b (x) select distinct (x) from x;
quit;
```

**Results**

On my machine, SAS9.4, Windows 64bit, the proc sort took about 4 seconds on average and the sql sort took about 5 seconds.  So yes the proc sort did run a little faster for this dataset.  Changing the number of rows, columns, field type being sorted on, and cardinality of the key can all change these results.

The insert into statement ran the quickest at 3.2 seconds.  Is your table that you are writing to a SAS dataset?  Or is it located in another database?  This will have the biggest impact on your results and should be the determining factor when choosing which step to run.

Comment: the libname is based on a server cluster.

Comment: Ok - so I have no idea how a cluster would divide the threads and assign the work for the above example.  All I can suggests is try multiple methods and pick whichever one works best for your environment.

Comment: Is your PROC SORT operating in ram here or is the dataset above your SORTSIZE?  If it's above that, then you will see worse results with PROC SORT over SQL if the SQL is able to (mostly) work in memory.

Comment: Hi Joe, in a dataset. But how would I know if the `PROC SORT`is done in RAM?